# Do I use an array for the inputs? What logical mistake am I making?

Tags: c, logic

Write a program that takes 10 inputs from the user one by one and pass that input to a function named `IsPrime()`, which then checks whether the number is prime or not and returns either 1 (for prime) or 0 (for composite). In `main()` on the basis of return value the input value is stored in an array of size of 10 elements from start to end (for prime) and end to start (for
composite). The Program should run like as following:

```
Enter Value: 19
Enter Value: 22
Enter Value: 51
Enter Value: 11
Enter Value: 28
Enter Value: 36
Enter Value: 29
Enter Value: 16
Enter Value: 23
Enter Value: 12
```

Elements in some order….
19 51 11 29 23 12 16 36 28 22

```
#include<stdio.h>
void IsPrime(int x,int *flag);
int main()
{
    int x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10;
    int p[10];
    int flag=1;
    int prime[10];
    int i;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x1);
    IsPrime(x1,&flag);
    p[0]=flag;
    prime[0]=x1;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x2);
    IsPrime(x2,&flag);
    p[1]=flag;
    prime[1]=x2;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x3);
    IsPrime(x3,&flag);
    p[2]=flag;
    prime[2]=x3;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x4);
    IsPrime(x4,&flag);
    p[3]=flag;
    prime[3]=x4;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x5);
    IsPrime(x5,&flag);
    p[4]=flag;
    prime[4]=x5;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x6);
    IsPrime(x6,&flag);
    p[5]=flag;
    prime[5]=x6;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x7);
    IsPrime(x7,&flag);
    p[6]=flag;
    prime[6]=x7;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x8);
    IsPrime(x8,&flag);
    p[7]=flag;
    prime[7]=x8;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x9);
    IsPrime(x9,&flag);
    p[8]=flag;
    prime[8]=x9;
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%d",&x10);
    IsPrime(x10,&flag);
    p[9]=flag;
    prime[9]=x10;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]==1)
        {
            prime[i]=prime[i];
        }
        else if(p[i]==0)
        {
            prime[9-i]=prime[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Elements in some order:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",prime[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void IsPrime(int x, int *flag)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<x;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        {
            *flag=0;
            break;
        }
        else
            *flag=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you first go back and change the code to use a loop instead of repeating essentially the same code 10 times.

Comment: To help you with the above: There's no point defining 10 versions of "x" if you are only using them as transitive storage.  A single `x` that you re-use is just fine.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, thank you. What do I do for the start to end (prime) and end to start (composite) part of the question? I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong here

Comment: Just store two indices: `int next_prime = 0, next_composite = 9;` -- then, when you read a value, call `IsPrime` and either: `p[next_prime++] = x;` or `p[next_composite--] = x;`  Provided you read exactly 10 values, you're guaranteed to populate all elements of the array, which you can then print out in order.  The entire program can pretty much be written in a handful of code lines.

Comment: This works, yayy! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of improving your code. For instance, 1) use a loop when reading user input and checking for primesand 2) put the numbers to their final location in the result array instead of sorting the array afterwards.

But you ask:

> What logical mistake am i making?

The problem is your sorting, i.e. this code

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(p[i]==1)
    {
        prime[i]=prime[i];
    }
    else if(p[i]==0)
    {
        prime[9-i]=prime[i];
    }
}
```

Assume you have these value:

```
p[] = {0, 1, ..., 0}
prime[] = {4, 3, ..., 8}
```

In the first loop (i.e. `i` equal 0), you execute:

```
prime[9-i]=prime[i]; or prime[9]=prime[0];
```

That's partly correct but you also overwrite the value at index 9, i.e. your array now looks like:

```
prime[] = {4, 3, ..., 4}
                      ^
                      4 is correct but you have lost the value 8
```

In the second loop (i.e. `i` equal 1), you execute:

```
prime[i]=prime[i]; or prime[1]=prime[1];
```

Since 3 was the first prime, you would really want `prime[0]=prime[1];`

Instead ofputting the result into the array in consecutive manner (and sorting afterwards), you should place them directly at their final position using two extra variables for index. Like:

```
int prime_index = 0;
int composite_index = 9;

printf("Enter Value: ");
scanf("%d",&x1);
IsPrime(x1,&flag);
if (flag)
{
    // prime
    prime[prime_index]=x1;
    ++prime_index;
}
else
{
    // composite
    prime[composite_index]=x1;
    --composite_index;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I get it now. Thank you so much for your help